sqlite3 callback gets run only after program is complete. Why then?
Disclaimer:   I'm a 40 year veteran software developer:  C, Java, lots of other stuff.  Trying to do simple Object Oriented program in Javascript under Node.js.   The threading and global memory management is baffling me.
I'm using a sqlite tutorial:
https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/query/
I'm running the query for all rows.
I have inserted this code into a Node.js file.   I have wrapped that simple query in a function call.   The function gets called, the query is submitted and the function returns to the calling code.  However at that point I have code to save the results as a json file and the data is not there.   When the program completes, THEN the callback from the query runs, but it is too late because the program saved no data and completed.
What do I need to insert to get it to actually run the query and call the callback?
Here is my 'Book.js' file:
    const fs = require('fs')
    // const Bible = require('./Bible.js');

    class Bible {
        constructor() {
            this.books = [];
            this.xrefs = [];
        }

        AddBook(book) {
            this.books.push(book);
            console.log('Book added: ' + book.name);
        }

        AddXref(xref) {
            this.xrefs.push(xref);
            console.log('Xref added: ' + xref);
        }
    }

    let theBible = new Bible();

    class Book {
        constructor(row) {
            this.ordinal     = row.order;
            this.name        = row.title_short;
            this.title       = row.title_full;
            this.category    = row.category;
            this.nChapters   = row.chapters;
        }
    }

    Book.load = function load( theBible ) {
        const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

    // open the database
        let db = new sqlite3.Database('./Data/bible-sqlite.db');

        let sql = `SELECT * FROM book_info`;

        db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            rows.forEach((row) => {
                book = new Book(row);
                theBible.AddBook(book);
                console.log(`Book[${book.ordinal}] ${book.name} loaded.`)
                console.log(book);
            });
        });

    // close the database connection
        db.close();
    }

    Book.saveAll = function saveAll(theBible) {

        if ( theBible != undefined && theBible.books != undefined) {
            console.log(theBible.books);

            // convert JSON object to a string
            const jsonData = JSON.stringify(theBible.books)

            // write JSON string to a file
            fs.writeFile('books.json', jsonData, err => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err
                }
                console.log('Books JSON data is saved.')
            })

        }

    }

    console.log('ready to load');
    Book.load(theBible);
    console.log("loaded, now to save it all.")
    Book.saveAll(theBible);
    console.log('done.');

    module.exports = Book;

Only after the final 5 lines of code are run and the program is done does the callback thread run.
What am I missing?
explained in the description.    I was expecting the callback to deliver the data after the call to the Book.load() function (Method) returns, but it only happens after the whole program is 'complete'.

Asynchronous programming is common in node.js and this is no exception.
Per the docs, the Database.all method "Binds parameters, executes the statement and calls the callback with all result rows.".
Execution will continue and it will invoke your callback function later, when the results are ready.
Your Book.load method can return a promise.  See https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/ for more information.

From my understanding you have to place your open the database and close the database connection code into an asynchronous operation. As you would need your program to wait for the DB connection and query.

saveAll  runs before load is finished, because db.all is asynchronous, see: How do I return the response from an asynchronous call? and JavaScript Asynchronous Programming and Callbacks
